# How to move the icon to the right end?

Tags: css, vue.js

This is how the code looks like in Vue.js template:

```
<modal v-model="isThematicSearchCardOpen" title="Card">
  <div>
    <form-row>
      <form-group :columns="12" title="Name">
        <text-input/>
      </form-group>
    </form-row>
    <form-row>
      <form-group :columns="12" title="Icon">
        <span style="margin-left: 20px;">None</span>
        <span>
          <icon-button default @click="upload" title="Save" icon="icon-folder-plus"/>
          <file-selector ref="fileSelector" @changed="selectFile" :filter="'.png, .jpeg, .jpg, .bpm'"/>
        </span>
      </form-group>
    </form-row>
  </div>
  <div slot="footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="create">Create</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" @click="cancelThematicSearchCard">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</modal>
```

I'd like to move the following part to the right end:

```
<span>
    <icon-button default @click="upload" title="Save" icon="icon-folder-plus"/>
    <file-selector ref="fileSelector" @changed="selectFile" :filter="'.png, .jpeg, .jpg, .bpm'"/>
</span>
```

We use Bootstrap 3 as basic CSS.

The row looks as following:

[image]

Comment: Add `float:right` to the `<span>`

Comment: It works. Thank you. But, I think it looks like a kind of hack with these inline styles. Is there any more proper solution, for example with using flexbox or similar?

Comment: You can always add a class and use stylesheets instead of inline styles. `flexbox` works too, you can look it up.

Comment: try with display: flex;   justify-content: flex-end; to the parent container of span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used flex box to achieve it. thanks

```css
.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<modal v-model="isThematicSearchCardOpen" title="Card">
  <div>
    <form-row>
      <form-group :columns="12" title="Name">
        <text-input/>
      </form-group>
    </form-row>
    <form-row>
      <form-group :columns="12" title="Icon" class="icon">
        <span style="margin-left: 20px;">None</span>
        <span>
          <icon-button default @click="upload" title="Save" class="fas fa-folder-plus" icon="icon-folder-plus"/>
          <file-selector ref="fileSelector" @changed="selectFile" :filter="'.png, .jpeg, .jpg, .bpm'"/>
        </span>
      </form-group>
    </form-row>
  </div>
  <div slot="footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="create">Create</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" @click="cancelThematicSearchCard">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `class="pull-right"` or

```
<div class="float-left">Float left on all viewport sizes</div><br>

<div class="float-right">Float right on all viewport sizes</div><br>
```

or

```
padding-left:500px;
padding-right:500px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. A trick here is that we use `margin-left: auto` for the icon

```css
.icon-block {
  display: flex;
}
.icon {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<modal v-model="isThematicSearchCardOpen" title="Card">
  <div>
    <form-row>
      <form-group :columns="12" title="Name">
        <text-input/>
      </form-group>
    </form-row>
    <form-row>
      <form-group :columns="12" title="Icon" class="icon-block">
        <span style="margin-left: 20px;">None</span>
        <span class="icon">
          <icon-button default @click="upload" title="Save" class="fas fa-folder-plus" icon="icon-folder-plus"/>
          <file-selector ref="fileSelector" @changed="selectFile" :filter="'.png, .jpeg, .jpg, .bpm'"/>
        </span>
      </form-group>
    </form-row>
  </div>
  <div slot="footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="create">Create</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" @click="cancelThematicSearchCard">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</modal>
```